# Visual Studio 2012 Can't find templates

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

After installing Visual Studio 2012 RTM on top of Visual Studio 2012 RC and creating a new ASP.Net Empty Web Application project, I am unable to add a New Web Form to my project. When attempting to add a new Web Form, I receive the error message:

> Could not find a part of the path ....\WebForm.zip\WebForm.vstemplate

This problem is listed on the connect site here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758581/could-not-find-itemtemplate-path

I can't register the workaround there, so I'm going to do it here, so hopefully someone else can find this. (Anyone know why the d@mnded register link doesn't work?)

Update:
I had to do this for the Class template also:
(My path)

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\ide\ItemTemplatesCache\web\csharp\1033\Class
Copied the Class folder and renamed it Class.zip
```

.

Comment: There, linked back to here on the Connect bug.

Answer (score 7):

To workaround this issue:

1. Open an explorer window to the path. In my case the path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\ide\ItemTemplatesCache\web\csharp\1033
2. Make a copy of the WebForm folder and name the copy WebForm.zip.
3. Try to add a new web form to the project. It should succeed this time.

Answer (score 4):

Try devenv /installvstemplates
It worked for me. #vs2010

Comment: Just an FYI, this is run from the Visual Studio Command Prompt, and must be run in Administrator mode.

Comment: Command "devenv" is not valid when used in the Command Window in VS17

Answer (score 1):

Chris' workaround did not work for me; but after resolving a path difference between his path and mine, it did work! Thanks Chris!

### First, what I tried and the result:

The path given in Chris' workaround existed on my machine as did the WebForm folder in that path so I dutifully followed Chris' instructions:

1. I copied and pasted the WebForm folder back into the 1033 folder (I'm using Windows 7 so copying and pasting in the same folder results in a 'WebForm - Copy' folder being created).
2. I renamed the folder to 'WebForm.zip' per Chris' instructions.
3. I then tried to add a new WebForm to my project and ...

***Same error as before!***

### What I noticed, what I then tried, and the result:

Chris gave me a clue when he stated:

> ***In my case*** the path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\ide\ItemTemplatesCache\web\csharp\1033

I decided to take a closer look at the path shown in my error dialog. Here is the error message and path I had:

> Could not find a part of the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\Web\1O33\WebForm.zip\WebForm.vstemplate.

Notice that `CSharp\Web` in my path differs from `web\csharp` in Chris' path. I would have thought Chris had made a typo in reproducing his path but ***both paths exist on my machine!  Wha...?!***

So having found this new folder after leaving the decoy behind (I'm sure that was the right path for Chris and others), I tried Chris' workaround again in this other folder and everything worked beautifully.

I am floored that there is such duplication in the Visual Studio file structure but, hey - why did I get this error in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

This is very frustrating. It is looking for a .zip folder.

The quick fix I used was to just copy all directories in whatever template folder it was complaining about and add a .zip to the end. Xcopy lets you do this efficiently. I had to do this a few times as VS uses a number of different locations for templates.

Open a console here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\Web\1033

If you navigate to one folder up (i.e. Web) and Shift+Click on the 1033 folder you get the option to "Open command window here"

Run this to rename all folders to folder.zip

```
for /d %d in (*.) do ren %d %d.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Had also nasty problem with it

This workd for me
copied the file to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE>

run in cmd the command:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE>vsixinstaller /s
:premium /v:11.0 dnntemplates.vsix